# Minimal form BACK button questionNumber interference

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I added a back button to a [Codrops form](https://tympanus.net/Development/MinimalForm/).

Here's a [webpage](http://dundaah.com/days/contact.php) from my website that has the form implemented.

The problem is that if a user presses the back button (for previous question) rapidly, the questionNumber counter overlaps and the numbers end up looking mixed up.

Could anyone help?

The full [JavaScript](http://dundaah.com/days/js/contactForm.js) and [CSS](http://dundaah.com/days/css/contactForm.css) The snippets below are the main concern.

```css
.simform .number {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0.4em 0;
 width: 3em;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 0.4em;
}

.simform .number:after {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 content: '/';
 opacity: 0.4;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.simform .number span {
 float: right;
 width: 40%;
 text-align: center;
}

.simform .number .number-current {
 float: left;
}

.simform .number-next {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}

.simform.show-next .number-current {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.simform.show-next .number-next {
 -webkit-animation: moveUpFromDown 0.4s both;
 animation: moveUpFromDown 0.4s both;
}

.simform.show-previous .number-current {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
 transform: translateY(100%);
}

.simform.show-previous .number-next {
 -webkit-animation: moveDownFromUp 0.4s both;
 animation: moveDownFromUp 0.4s both;
}
```

Comment: where's the html?

Comment: We also need the JS.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The fix:**

a) Change section near line 275:

```
// changes the current question number
stepsForm.prototype._updateQuestionNumber = function() {

    if (this.nextQuestionNum) this.questionStatus.removeChild( this.nextQuestionNum ); // remove if it still exists (when user clicks forwards or back before animation ends)
    this.nextQuestionNum = document.createElement( 'span' );

    this.nextQuestionNum.className = 'number-next';
    this.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML = Number( this.current + 1 );
    // insert it in the DOM
    this.questionStatus.appendChild( this.nextQuestionNum );
};
```

b) Change section near line 195:

```
    // after animation ends, remove class "show-next" from form element and change current question placeholder
    var self = this,
        onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            if( self.isFilled ) {
                self._submit();
            }
            else {
                classie.removeClass( self.el, 'show-next' );
                self.currentNum.innerHTML = self.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML;
                self.questionStatus.removeChild( self.nextQuestionNum );
                self.nextQuestionNum = null; // set to null to indicate that it has been removed

                // force the focus on the next input
                nextQuestion.querySelector( 'input' ).focus();
            }
        };
```

b) Change section near line 257:

```
    // after animation ends, remove class "show-previous" from form element and change current question placeholder
    var self = this,
        onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            if( self.isFilled ) {
                self._submit();
            }
            else {
                classie.removeClass( self.el, 'show-previous' );
                self.currentNum.innerHTML = self.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML;
                self.questionStatus.removeChild( self.nextQuestionNum );
                self.nextQuestionNum = null; // set to null to indicate that it has been removed

                // force the focus on the next input
                previousQuestion.querySelector( 'input' ).focus();
            }
        };
```

**The Explanation:**

The problem is this section:

```
// changes the current question number
    stepsForm.prototype._updateQuestionNumber = function() {
        // first, create next question number placeholder
        this.nextQuestionNum = document.createElement( 'span' );
        this.nextQuestionNum.className = 'number-next';
        this.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML = Number( this.current + 1 );
        // insert it in the DOM
        this.questionStatus.appendChild( this.nextQuestionNum );
    };
```

Specifically, the line `this.nextQuestionNum = document.createElement( 'span' );`.

What is happening is it creates the `span` and holds the reference to it (`this.nextQuestionNum`). Once the animation finishes that element is destroyed using that reference.

When the user clicks too quickly (ie. faster than the animation runs) the above code executes a second time and so creates a new `span` and holds the reference to that. At this point if the original `span` hasn't been deleted then the code has lost its pointer to it and hangs around like a bad smell.

So the `if` statement checks whether it is not null and removes it.

Comment: For clarity, the changes are: a) the addition of `if (this.nextQuestionNum)..` line; and in b) & c) the addition of the `self.nextQuestionNum = null;` line.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the console you have a "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. at HTMLDivElement.onEndTransitionFn (http://dundaah.com/days/js/contactForm.js:255:26)".

I suspect that when you press the button quickly, you have two events almost sent at the same time, which try to remove the same node (and probably re-add it somewhere). You need to make sure the Dom node exists when you do `self.questionStatus.removeChild( self.nextQuestionNum );`

Answer (score 1):

what is happening is this function:

```
// changes the current question number
stepsForm.prototype._updateQuestionNumber = function() {
    // first, create next question number placeholder
    this.nextQuestionNum = document.createElement( 'span' );
    this.nextQuestionNum.className = 'number-next';
    this.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML = Number( this.current + 1 );
    // insert it in the DOM
    this.questionStatus.appendChild( this.nextQuestionNum );
};
```

is creating a new span element when the button is previous button or next button is pressed.
After which the calling function `stepsForm.prototype._previousQuestion` runs this code block:

```
// after animation ends, remove class "show-previous" from form element and change current question placeholder
        var self = this,
            onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                if( self.isFilled ) {
                    self._submit();
                }
                else {
                    classie.removeClass( self.el, 'show-previous' );
                    self.currentNum.innerHTML = self.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML;
                    self.questionStatus.removeChild( self.nextQuestionNum );
                    // force the focus on the next input
                    previousQuestion.querySelector( 'input' ).focus();
                }
            };
```

The issue is, when the button is pressed rapidly, the first function runs twice before the second code block is able to remove the first child, so it only removes one child, and the other is left in the document.

You could try moving this line

```
self.questionStatus.removeChild( self.nextQuestionNum );
```

into the `stepsForm.prototype._updateQuestionNumber` function with some simple validation to avoid possible errors, like so:

```
// changes the current question number
stepsForm.prototype._updateQuestionNumber = function() {
    // if nextQuestionNum exists remove it
    if (this.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML){
        self.questionStatus.removeChild( self.nextQuestionNum );
    }
    // first, create next question number placeholder
    this.nextQuestionNum = document.createElement( 'span' );
    this.nextQuestionNum.className = 'number-next';
    this.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML = Number( this.current + 1 );
    // insert it in the DOM
    this.questionStatus.appendChild( this.nextQuestionNum );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As very well clarified from everybody, when the user clicks quickly on the back (or next, the script breaks with quick clicks on next too), you try to remove something that's not there anymore. A quick fix could be to querySelector the node you want to remove (the first picked node is always the one you want) inside your `onEndTransitionFn` function.

```
self
    .nextQuestionNum
    .parentNode
    .removeChild(self.nextQuestionNum.parentNode.querySelector('.number-next'))
```